# Change css class depending on value

Tags: css, razor

took me a while to decide to post this question as I don't want to hassle with silly ones. But couldn't really see the answer in my web browsing.

In a Razor view. I have a list of strings to display (they are known, but quite a few) and I would like to put them in an  with different colour. In order to avoid the repetition I though of using this

```
@foreach (var planGroup in Model.Plans)
{
  <h2 class= "@planGroup.Key" >@planGroup.Key</h2>
  @* .... *@
}
```

It works, but is there a cleaner way?I was thinking of data-annotations and Jquery but as far as I understand it is even dirtier, isn't it? besides is much more to do for just this.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want each link to be a certain color or maybe just alternating colors? You probably don't need classes for this. (btw, I'm not familiar with Razor)

Comment: One different colour for each

Comment: You don't need jQuery to style based on an element's `data-*` attributes.  It won't be that much different looking than using a class, but in exchange for slightly worse performance (if that's a concern for you) you won't have to worry about your attribute having spaces.

Comment: I would tend to stick with what you have, as long as they are known values that can be placed into your CSS file as classes. Otherwise, I would be tempted to add another property to my view model to handle the CSS class to use something like `planGroup.CssClass`.

Comment: Thanks, very insightful. None of them have spaces so I will stick to this.